# pandas feeding slice as pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index getting TypeError: slice indices must be integers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, slice

I am brain locked. I am getting the error below and can't see why, the index is an int64 so??? . I want to go through the data set and find all the changed rows and note their index locations into an array. Then use the array to go to each location in turn, print out the next two rows then get the next location.

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

here is the code segment and data.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['edward',1],['edward',0],['edward',0],['norm',1],['norm',0],['norm',0] ]

df_names = pd.DataFrame( data )

criteria = df_names[1] == 1

df_just_changes = df_names[ criteria ]

print(df_names)
print(df_just_changes .index)
print("type of  df_just_changes.index {} ".format(type( df_just_changes.index ) ) )
print("type of  df_just_changes.index[0] {} ".format(type( df_just_changes.index[0] ) ) )
print( df_names.values[df_just_changes.index : 2 ])
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to mask out the 'changed' only rows?

Comment: `df_just_changes.index` returns an array, not an `int`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry I changed the question to show what I am trying to do which is to go through a larger data find where a column is 1 then print out the next two row and then go back to the next value in the array and do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps use a mask and 'fillna' to forward fill (ffill) the mask.
Something like:

```
# make criteria false values NaN
criteria[~criteria] == None
# forward fill the NaNsafter the True values limiting to 2
criteria = criteria.fillna(method="ffill", limit=1)
# whatever's left, make False
criteria = criteria.fillna(False)
# and you mask is complete
df_changed = df_names[criteria]
```

Comment: thanks but I don't want to do that.  I WAS hoping I could just find the index of the rows when they change ( the data set is sorted) and use that to go directly to them and print out the following two rows.

Comment: which is exactly what this does. The criteria mask IS the masked index of the changed rows and you simply add two rows to the mask. Best read up on Pandas indexing.

Comment: I agree that's what it does and for that I thank you. I just don't like the look of it. I wanted to use the indices of the changed rows, then consider using iloc to get the next two rows.  I will take your advice and remind myself as to how all this works. I suppose it's block manager time again. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your approach will require you to iterate over the dataframe, which is possible of course but doesn't leverage the broadcast capabilities of pandas

Comment: no it doesn't iterate, I get the index of the change fields put them into an array then use the array to go directly to the data index locations and just add two to the index pointer thus getting the rows directly. Where is the iteration please? I am just iterating through the array of index locations NOT the data itself.

Comment: Never said you are iterating, said you would need to iterate in order to move your index pointer along. Your suggested answer doesn't work because you're trying to project a slice onto an array and not onto each element of the array. If you don't like the mask and fillna, try a mask and the shift method, either way indexing with a mask is how pandas will help you.

Comment: thanks will. I'm going back to first principals on this.